# Can i make a method that takes arguments that it will execute

Tags: java, methods, lwjgl

I will form my question new.

This is what i currently have(LWJGL not JButton):

```
public static boolean isButtonClicked(String buttonName){
    Button b = getButton(buttonName);
    float mouseY = essentials.Boot.HEIGHT - Mouse.getY() - 1;
    if (Mouse.getX() > b.getX() && Mouse.getX() < b.getX() + b.getWidth() &&
        mouseY > b.getY() && mouseY < b.getY() + b.getHeight()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And thats in my main class

```
if(Ui.isButtonClicked("buttonName")/*Takes a name of a button as a argument*/){
        System.out.println();
}
```

So i dont want there to be several if statements in my main. But its always diffrent what i want to do if the button is clicked. So my question is if there is a way to do something like this. If you still dont know what i mean im just going to delete the post.

Comment: Please take a class in Java or read an introductory Java programming book.

Comment: If you are asking if you can parameterize methods, then the answer is yes... .provided you are the one defining them.

Comment: You want a method as a parameter?

Comment: Looks like Javascript

Comment: It is like passing function as an argument to the method i think? Which is functional programming similar like lambda expressions??

Comment: What im trying to achive is i have a for loop and i dont want the whole loop to be written in my main class. So is it possible to tell the method what it should do inside that it shortens my main class.

Comment: Put that example in main question. Don't force people to search for crucial information in comments.

Comment: Your question is related with rendering in java. Some examples you can find here: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jlist-custom-renderer-example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366204/how-would-an-abstract-render-method-work-java and here:

Comment: Why are you not using `Action`s or `ActionLIstener`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Interface/Lambda to pass a method to another method. for example:

```
public interface Procedure {
    void act();
}
public void executeCommand(Procedure proc){
    proc.act();
}
//...
// pass a method using lambda expression:
    executeCommand(()->{system.out.println("Hello world"});

//pass a method using traditional way (anonymous class)
    executeCommand(new Procedure() {

        public void act() {
            system.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you mean some thing like this:

```
public static void doSmth(String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
 }
//When you call it
doSmth("Hello world");
```